# Google Chromium / Chrome. Extension. Change text in address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I make the address bar tab displays a single site, and the contents of the tab corresponds to a different site?

P.S. I know English very poor, sorry.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea - it could be used to trick users into entering private details thinking they are on a trusted site - and is probably therefore impossible for security reasons.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to deceive anybody.
I just write the extension-anonymizer ... And I need to do to be displayed in the address bar URL without any extra parts that prevent copying it, etc.

Comment: And can I somehow get around this, say, a GET request? Or can not be in any way?

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking to write is an HTTP proxy. Looking up that term might give you some clues...